# 'Only SOCKS5 supported' OpenFire error with XMPP File Transfer

Tags: proxy, xmpp, openfire, socks, xmppframework

**My Question :** I'm doing file transfer via XMPP on iOS using the XMPPFramework and OpenFire. The base of my code is from the following [tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/building-a-jabber-client-for-ios-server-setup). The target appears to accept the proxy as the streamhost, but when the requester attempt to do the same, OpenFire reports the following error. Why is it failing and how can I fix it?

**OpenFire error -**

```
2012.06.12 14:38:40 org.jivesoftware.openfire.filetransfer.proxy.ProxyConnectionManager - Error processing file transfer proxy connection 
java.io.IOException: Only SOCKS5 supported 
at org.jivesoftware.openfire.filetransfer.proxy.ProxyConnectionManager.processConnection(ProxyConnectionManager.java:158) 
at org.jivesoftware.openfire.filetransfer.proxy.ProxyConnectionManager.access$200(ProxyConnectionManager.java:57) 
at org.jivesoftware.openfire.filetransfer.proxy.ProxyConnectionManager$1$1.run(ProxyConnectionManager.java:127) 
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441) 
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303) 
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

**My OpenFire XMPP settings -** (note that I've set the external ip of the proxy here)

```
xmpp.auth.anonymous - true
xmpp.client.compression.policy - disabled
xmpp.client.idle - -1
xmpp.client.idle.ping - false
xmpp.domain - beta.myCompany.co.uk
xmpp.enabled - true
xmpp.filetransfer.enabled - true
xmpp.offline.quota - 102400
xmpp.offline.type - bounce
xmpp.proxy.enabled - true
xmpp.proxy.externalip - 10.95.xxx.xxx (this is the ip of my server)
xmpp.proxy.port - 7777
xmpp.proxy.transfer.required - false
xmpp.server.compression.policy - disabled
xmpp.server.dialback.enabled - false
xmpp.server.socket.active - true
xmpp.session.conflict-limit - 0
xmpp.session.conflict.limit - 0
xmpp.socket.ssl.active - true
```

**Logs -**

```
2012-06-12 16:26:20.848 JabberClient[2711:207] RECIEVED IN APP DELEGATE - <iq xmlns="jabber:client" type="result" to="myUsername@beta.myCompany.co.uk/3a62c56a" id="4FC4CE04-DA8E-4CC2-B412-40D1C346F682" from="friendsUsername@beta.myCompany.co.uk/ee69d0fa"><si xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/si"><feature xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/feature-neg"><x xmlns="jabber:x:data" type="submit"><field var="stream-method"><value>http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams</value></field></x></feature></si></iq>
2012-06-12 16:26:20.849 JabberClient[2711:207] Attempting XEP65 connection to friendsUsername@beta.myCompany.co.uk/ee69d0fa
2012-06-12 16:26:20.849 JabberClient[2711:207] TURNSocket DELEGATE STARTING
2012-06-12 16:26:20.851 JabberClient[2711:6103] SENT - <iq type="get" to="beta.myCompany.co.uk" id="C8A201C4-EC3B-49CC-8BF4-9604B872EB19"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items"/></iq>
2012-06-12 16:26:20.856 JabberClient[2711:1e03] RECIEVED IN TURN SOCKET - <iq xmlns="jabber:client" type="result" id="C8A201C4-EC3B-49CC-8BF4-9604B872EB19" from="beta.myCompany.co.uk" to="myUsername@beta.myCompany.co.uk/3a62c56a"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items"><item jid="pubsub.beta.myCompany.co.uk" name="Publish-Subscribe service"/><item jid="broadcast.beta.myCompany.co.uk" name="Broadcast service"/><item jid="search.beta.myCompany.co.uk" name="User Search"/><item jid="conference.beta.myCompany.co.uk" name="Public Chatrooms"/><item jid="proxy.beta.myCompany.co.uk" name="Socks 5 Bytestreams Proxy"/></query></iq>
2012-06-12 16:26:20.857 JabberClient[2711:1e03] SENT - <iq type="get" to="proxy.beta.myCompany.co.uk" id="92BF3339-987C-4A1E-8657-D8AE666DDC32"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"/></iq>
2012-06-12 16:26:20.857 JabberClient[2711:207] RECIEVED IN APP DELEGATE - <iq xmlns="jabber:client" type="result" id="C8A201C4-EC3B-49CC-8BF4-9604B872EB19" from="beta.myCompany.co.uk" to="myUsername@beta.myCompany.co.uk/3a62c56a"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items"><item jid="pubsub.beta.myCompany.co.uk" name="Publish-Subscribe service"></item><item jid="broadcast.beta.myCompany.co.uk" name="Broadcast service"></item><item jid="search.beta.myCompany.co.uk" name="User Search"></item><item jid="conference.beta.myCompany.co.uk" name="Public Chatrooms"></item><item jid="proxy.beta.myCompany.co.uk" name="Socks 5 Bytestreams Proxy"></item></query></iq>
2012-06-12 16:26:20.862 JabberClient[2711:6103] RECIEVED IN TURN SOCKET - <iq xmlns="jabber:client" type="result" id="92BF3339-987C-4A1E-8657-D8AE666DDC32" from="proxy.beta.myCompany.co.uk" to="myUsername@beta.myCompany.co.uk/3a62c56a"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"><identity category="proxy" name="SOCKS5 Bytestreams Service" type="bytestreams"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"/></query></iq>
2012-06-12 16:26:20.863 JabberClient[2711:6103] SENT - <iq type="get" to="proxy.beta.myCompany.co.uk" id="D13DE459-63EA-4CD6-97ED-8565559DF298"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams"/></iq>
2012-06-12 16:26:20.863 JabberClient[2711:207] RECIEVED IN APP DELEGATE - <iq xmlns="jabber:client" type="result" id="92BF3339-987C-4A1E-8657-D8AE666DDC32" from="proxy.beta.myCompany.co.uk" to="myUsername@beta.myCompany.co.uk/3a62c56a"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"><identity category="proxy" name="SOCKS5 Bytestreams Service" type="bytestreams"></identity><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams"></feature><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"></feature></query></iq>
2012-06-12 16:26:20.874 JabberClient[2711:6103] RECIEVED IN TURNSOCKET - <iq xmlns="jabber:client" type="result" id="D13DE459-63EA-4CD6-97ED-8565559DF298" from="proxy.beta.myCompany.co.uk" to="myUsername@beta.myCompany.co.uk/3a62c56a"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams"><streamhost jid="proxy.beta.myCompany.co.uk" host="10.95.xxx.xxx" port="7777"/></query></iq>
2012-06-12 16:26:20.875 JabberClient[2711:6103] SENT - <iq type="set" from="myUsername@beta.myCompany.co.uk/3a62c56a" to="friendsUsername@beta.myCompany.co.uk/ee69d0fa" id="4FC4CE04-DA8E-4CC2-B412-40D1C346F682"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams" sid="4FC4CE04-DA8E-4CC2-B412-40D1C346F682" mode="tcp"><streamhost xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams" jid="proxy.beta.myCompany.co.uk" host="10.95.xxx.xxx" port="7777"/></query></iq>
2012-06-12 16:26:20.875 JabberClient[2711:207] RECIEVED IN APP DELEGATE - <iq xmlns="jabber:client" type="result" id="D13DE459-63EA-4CD6-97ED-8565559DF298" from="proxy.beta.myCompany.co.uk" to="myUsername@beta.myCompany.co.uk/3a62c56a"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams"></query></iq>
2012-06-12 16:26:20.916 JabberClient[2711:1e03] RECIEVED IN TURN SOCKET - <iq xmlns="jabber:client" type="result" to="myUsername@beta.myCompany.co.uk/3a62c56a" id="4FC4CE04-DA8E-4CC2-B412-40D1C346F682" from="friendsUsername@beta.myCompany.co.uk/ee69d0fa"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams" sid="4FC4CE04-DA8E-4CC2-B412-40D1C346F682"><streamhost-used jid="proxy.beta.myCompany.co.uk"/></query></iq>
2012-06-12 16:26:20.917 JabberClient[2711:1e03] TURNSocket: initiatorConnect: proxy.beta.myCompany.co.uk(10.95.xxx.xxx:7777)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's have a look at Openfire's source code. That's easy since it's an open source project. :)

[ProxyConnectionManager.java:158](http://fisheye.igniterealtime.org/browse/openfire/trunk/src/java/org/jivesoftware/openfire/filetransfer/proxy/ProxyConnectionManager.java?hb=true#to158) tells us that Openfire expects an "5" as first byte send through the stream (i.e. the SOCKS5 connection), or otherwise the Exception you see will get thrown. Which seems to be correct according to [RFC1928 (SOCKS Protocol Version 5) Section 3](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1928.txt).

So without digging deeper and having any knowledge on XMPP on iOS, I would guess that there is something not correct implemented within xmppframework on iOS. I hope I could point you into the right direction.

Comment: Thanks Flow. Your advice encouraged me to delve deeper into my code, and I realised I wasn't correctly implementing a couple of methods, and thus the requester was not sending the necessary XEP-0065 response with an <activate> element. Now I have a successful XEP-0065 connection and the error in OpenFire has vanished :) . (However, I haven't yet worked out how to use the connection to send a file :S ).

Comment: You are welcome. I can only recommend that you record all XMPP stanzas (openfire audit) and read the XEPs in order to find out why the file transfer fails. Good luck.

Comment: If there is a way to read the stanzas from within openfire, I have missed it (my colleague set up the openfire server, not me). Do you how to view this? I can't see them in the logs.